# likelihood and fisher information of two dependent variables

Tags: statistics, information-theory, log-likelihood, fisher-information, mutual-information

Let $\{X, Y\}$ be two sets of variables that depend on the  parameter $\theta$. Let $z_1 = f_1(X,Y), z_2 = f_2(X,Y)$ be two variables constructed from $\{X, Y\}$. The functions $f_i$'s are known. $I_{z_1, z_2}(\theta) $ and $I_{X, Y}(\theta)$ are the Fisher information from $\{z_1, z_2\}$ and $\{X, Y\}$ variables.

We can write $$I_{z_1, z_2}(\theta) \leq I_{X, Y}(\theta)$$ where the equality holds when $z_i$'s are sufficient statistic ([source](http://survivor99.com/entropy/2007_2/fisher_information.htm)). How do we extract (i) the likelihood $p(z_1,z_2)$ and Fisher information (ii) $I_{z_1, z_2}(\theta)$ from the primary variables' likelihood and information – $p(X,Y)$ and $I_{X, Y}(\theta)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let us recall the definition of an sufficient statistic. Given a model $(P_{\theta}(dw))_{\theta\in \Theta}=e^{\ell_w(\theta)}\nu(dw)$ on $\Omega$, consider a map   $v=\varphi(w)$ from $\Omega$ to some
mesurable space $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$. Denote by $P_{\theta}(dw,dv)$ the joint distribution of $(w,\varphi(w))$ in $\Omega\times\Omega_1$ (thus actually concentrated on the 'curve' $\{(w,v)\ ; v=\varphi(w)\}.$ We desintegrate \begin{equation}\label{Q}P_{\theta}(dw,dv)=H_{\theta}(dv)K_{\theta}(v,dw)\end{equation} where $H_{\theta}(dv)$ is the marginal distribution of the random variable $V=\varphi(w)$ and where the transition probability kernel $K_{\theta}(v,dw)$ is the conditional distribution of $w$ given $V=v.$ We shall say that $\varphi$ is an sufficient statistic if $\theta\mapsto K_{\theta}$ is a constant.

Proposition: Consider a  Fisher model $(P_{\theta}(dw))_{\theta\in \Theta}$ on $\Omega$. Consider also a measurable map $v=\varphi(w)$ from $\Omega$ to some
measurable space $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$. Suppose that the image   $H(dv)$ of $\nu(dw)$ by $w\mapsto v= \varphi(w)$ exists. Consider   the image $(H_{\theta}(dv))_{\theta\in \Theta}$ on $\Omega_1$ of $(P_{\theta}(dw))_{\theta\in \Theta}$ by $w\mapsto v= \varphi(w).$ Then $(H_{\theta})_{\theta\in \Theta}$ is a Fisher model, with $H_{\theta}(dv)=e^{h_v(\theta)}H(dv).$ Let $J(\theta)$ be its information matrix. Then
$$I(\theta)-J(\theta)=\int _{\Omega}[(\ell_w'(\theta)-h_{\varphi(w)}'(\theta))\otimes (\ell_w'(\theta)-h_{\varphi(w)}'(\theta))]P_{\theta}(dw).$$
In particular $I(\theta)-J(\theta)$ is semi positive definite. Furthermore  $I(\theta)-J(\theta)=0$ for all $\theta\in \Theta$ if and only if $\varphi$ is an sufficient statistic.

Comment: I am not sure your answer addresses my question of extracting likelihood function and information of $z_1,z_2$ from $X,Y$.

Comment: Just apply to $\Omega=\Omega_1=R^2$  and $\varphi(X,Y)=(f_1(X,Y),f_2(X,Y)).$

Comment: I got a few questions. (i) By a Fisher model $P_{\theta} (dw)$, do you mean the likelihood of $w$ variables? (ii) How do we obtain the function $\ell_w (\theta)$ from ($P_{\theta} (dw)$)? (iii) How is the map $H_\theta (dv)$ calculated from $P_{\theta} (dw)$ (an example would be extremely useful).

Comment: A Fisher model is $P_{\theta}(dw)=e^{\ell_w(\theta)}\nu(dw)$ where $w\in \Omega$, $\theta \in \Theta\subset R^d$ and $\nu(dw)$ is a measure on $\Omega$ such that $\int_{\Omega}P_{\theta}(dw)=1$ for all $\theta$ which implies  $\int_{\Omega}\ell'_w(\theta)P_{\theta}(dw)=0$ and  $\int_{\Omega}\ell'_w(\theta)\otimes \ell'_w(\theta)+\ell''_w(\theta)P_{\theta}(dw)=0.$ Example of model which NOT a Fisher one: $\frac{1}{\theta}1_{[0,\theta]}(w)dw$ with $\Theta=\Omega=(0,\infty)$ :you cannot take the log of $\frac{1}{\theta}1_{[0,\theta]}(w)$ for revealing $\ell_{w}(\theta).$ Here $\nu(dw)=dw.$

Comment: The computation of $H_{\theta}(dv)$ is done by its definition. But I will think of a nice explicit example, wait for a while.